# CKEDITOR.appendTo(div_id) not directly inserted into html

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, ckeditor

I'm creating a ckeditor plugin with a dialog. In the dialog I have a ckeditor.
When I use `CKEDITOR.appendTo(div_id)` it is not directly pushed to the html. That way I can not set the `innerHTML`.

```
onLoad : function(){
    // textareas == the textareas in the dialog
    var textareas = $('.cke_dialog_ui_input_textarea');
    // features_id == the id of the first div in the td
    var features_id = textareas[1].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute('id');
    // features == first div in td
    var features = textareas[1];
    // features_innerhtml == html from the textarea
    var features_innerhtml = textareas[1].innerHtml;

    // create ckeditor for features inside features_id div
    CKEDITOR.appendTo(features_id);//here it should have created the iframe etc.

    // change textarea style to 'display:none;'
    features.setAttribute('style','display:none;');

    //because the ckeditor iframe does not yet exists i can not insert my html later on             
    //select iframe
    var iframe = $('#' + features_id).children().children().children().children()[3];

    //set inner html of iframe
    iframe.contentWindow.document.childNodes[1].childNodes[1].innerHTML(features_innerhtml);
}
```

when the script is finished and the ckeditor dialog is fully loaded, the ckeditor shows up, but it is empty. What am i doing wrong?

**EDIT**
html as requested:

```
<div class="cke cke_reset_all cke_1 cke_editor_ckeditor_dialog" dir="ltr" lang="nl" role="application">
<table class="cke_dialog cke_browser_webkit cke_ltr" aria-labelledby="cke_dialog_title_138" style="position: fixed; top: 337px; left: 751.5px; z-index: 10010;" role="dialog">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td role="presentation">
                <div class="cke_dialog_body" role="presentation">
                    <div id="cke_dialog_title_138" class="cke_dialog_title" role="presentation" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">Blok aanmaken</div>
                    <a id="cke_dialog_close_button_138" class="cke_dialog_close_button" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Sluiten" role="button" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><span class="cke_label">X</span>
                    </a>
                    <div id="cke_dialog_tabs_138" class="cke_dialog_tabs" role="tablist">
                        <a class="cke_dialog_tab cke_dialog_tab_selected" cke_first="" title="Tekst" id="cke_tab1_155" href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1" hidefocus="true" role="tab" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">Tekst</a>
                        <a class="cke_dialog_tab" cke_last="" title="Style" id="cke_tab2_160" href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1" hidefocus="true" role="tab" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">Style</a>
                    </div>
                    <table class="cke_dialog_contents" role="presentation">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td id="cke_dialog_contents_138" class="cke_dialog_contents_body" role="presentation" style="width: 400px; height: 200px;">
                                    <div role="tabpanel" id="cke_154_uiElement" class="cke_dialog_ui_vbox cke_dialog_page_contents" style="width: 100%;" aria-labelledby="cke_tab1_155" name="tab1" aria-hidden="false">
                                        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:100%;" align="left">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td role="presentation" class="cke_dialog_ui_vbox_child">
                                                        <div role="presentation" id="cke_144_uiElement" class="cke_dialog_ui_text">
                                                            <label class="cke_dialog_ui_labeled_label" id="cke_143_label" for="cke_142_textInput">Titel</label>
                                                            <div class="cke_dialog_ui_labeled_content" role="presentation">
                                                                <div class="cke_dialog_ui_input_text" role="presentation">
                                                                    <input class="cke_dialog_ui_input_text" id="cke_142_textInput" type="text" aria-labelledby="cke_143_label">
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td role="presentation" class="cke_dialog_ui_vbox_child">
                                                        <div role="presentation" id="cke_147_uiElement" class="cke_dialog_ui_textarea ckeditor_features">
                                                            <label class="cke_dialog_ui_labeled_label" id="cke_146_label" for="cke_145_textarea">Kenmerken</label>
                                                            <div class="cke_dialog_ui_labeled_content" role="presentation">
                                                                <div class="cke_dialog_ui_input_textarea" role="presentation">
                                                                    <textarea class="cke_dialog_ui_input_textarea" id="cke_145_textarea" rows="5" cols="20" aria-labelledby="cke_146_label" style="display:none;"></textarea>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td role="presentation" class="cke_dialog_ui_vbox_child">
                                                        <div role="presentation" id="cke_150_uiElement" class="cke_dialog_ui_textarea ckeditor_introduction">
                                                            <label class="cke_dialog_ui_labeled_label" id="cke_149_label" for="cke_148_textarea">Introductie</label>
                                                            <div class="cke_dialog_ui_labeled_content" role="presentation">
                                                                <div class="cke_dialog_ui_input_textarea" role="presentation">
                                                                    <textarea class="cke_dialog_ui_input_textarea" id="cke_148_textarea" rows="5" cols="20" aria-labelledby="cke_149_label"></textarea>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td role="presentation" class="cke_dialog_ui_vbox_child">
                                                        <div role="presentation" id="cke_153_uiElement" class="cke_dialog_ui_text">
                                                            <label class="cke_dialog_ui_labeled_label" id="cke_152_label" for="cke_151_textInput">Meerinfo Link</label>
                                                            <div class="cke_dialog_ui_labeled_content" role="presentation">
                                                                <div class="cke_dialog_ui_input_text" role="presentation">
                                                                    <input class="cke_dialog_ui_input_text" id="cke_151_textInput" type="text" aria-labelledby="cke_152_label">
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                    <div role="tabpanel" id="cke_159_uiElement" class="cke_dialog_ui_vbox cke_dialog_page_contents" style="width: 100%; display: none;" aria-labelledby="cke_tab2_160" name="tab2" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:100%;" align="left">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td role="presentation" class="cke_dialog_ui_vbox_child">
                                                        <div role="presentation" id="cke_158_uiElement" class="cke_dialog_ui_text color {hash:true}">
                                                            <label class="cke_dialog_ui_labeled_label" id="cke_157_label" for="cke_156_textInput">Achtergrond Kleur</label>
                                                            <div class="cke_dialog_ui_labeled_content" role="presentation">
                                                                <div class="cke_dialog_ui_input_text" role="presentation">
                                                                    <input class="cke_dialog_ui_input_text" id="cke_156_textInput" type="text" aria-labelledby="cke_157_label">
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td id="cke_dialog_footer_138" class="cke_dialog_footer" role="presentation">
                                    <table role="presentation" id="cke_166_uiElement" class="cke_dialog_ui_hbox cke_dialog_footer_buttons">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr class="cke_dialog_ui_hbox">
                                                <td class="cke_dialog_ui_hbox_first" role="presentation">
                                                    <a style="undefined" href="javascript:void(0)" title="OK" hidefocus="true" class="cke_dialog_ui_button cke_dialog_ui_button_ok" role="button" aria-labelledby="cke_162_label" id="cke_163_uiElement"><span id="cke_162_label" class="cke_dialog_ui_button">OK</span>
                                                    </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="cke_dialog_ui_hbox_last" role="presentation">
                                                    <a style="undefined" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Annuleren" hidefocus="true" class="cke_dialog_ui_button cke_dialog_ui_button_cancel" role="button" aria-labelledby="cke_164_label" id="cke_165_uiElement"><span id="cke_164_label" class="cke_dialog_ui_button">Annuleren</span>
                                                    </a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can u post the html code?

Comment: first try an alert and check if u have anything in features_innerhtml before appending

Comment: I tryed an alert(features_innerhtml) and got 'abc' back which is correct. The question is, why is the iframe not created on `appendTo()`?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my appendTo to the following:

```
CKEDITOR.appendTo(features_id, null, features_innerhtml);
```

At first I only specified the div it should create the ckeditor in. In [the documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.html)  it said the following:

`CKEDITOR.appendTo(elementOrId, config, data)`
I had no config items so I use `null` for the data i use `features_innerhtml`.
so I specified the data inside the appendTo instead of setting the innerHTML later:)